# Neon optimization of interlaced YUYV to gray

Tags: c, image-processing, arm, neon

I have the following C code that converts an interlaced webcam YUYV to gray:

```
void convert_yuyv_to_y(const void *src, char *dest) {
    int x, y;
    char *Y, *gray;
    //get only Y component for grayscale from (Y1)(U1,2)(Y2)(V1,2)
    for (y = 0; y < CAM_HEIGHT; y++) {
        Y = src + (CAM_WIDTH * 2 * y);
        gray = dest + (CAM_WIDTH * y);
        for (x=0; x < CAM_WIDTH; x += 2) {
            gray[x] = *Y;
            Y += 2;
            gray[x + 1] = *Y;
            Y += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to optimize such function with some neon instructions?

Comment: Do you have a benchmarking framework in place so you can measure the benefits of any changes?

Comment: Basic approach: Read 2 registers at a time interleaved, and store only one: `vld2.8 { d0, d1}, [r0]!; vst1.8 d0, [r1]!`; Advanced stuff: align to 16 bytes, use multiple individual paths, make sure that those paths do not fight from the same cache lines, use multiple threads.

Comment: @Aki Suihkonen: Could you wrap up an answer for your basic approach including some code?

Comment: You can also compile it using "-Wall -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=8 -O2 -c" with gcc.

Comment: I'm also dropping http://code.google.com/p/libyuv/ as another reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a starting point. From here you can do cache preloads, loop unrolling, etc. The best performance will happen when more NEON registers are involved to prevent data stalls.

```
 .equ CAM_HEIGHT, 480 @ fill in the correct values
 .equ CAM_WIDTH,  640

@
@ Call from C as convert_yuyv_to_y(const void *src, char *dest);
@
convert_yuyv_to_y:
  mov r2,#CAM_HEIGHT  
cvtyuyv_top_y:
  mov r3,#CAM_WIDTH
cvtyuyv_top_x:
  vld2.8 {d0,d1},[r0]!   @ assumes source width is a multiple of 8
  vst1.8 {d0},[r1]!      @ work with 8 pixels at a time
  subs r3,r3,#8          @ x+=8
  bgt cvtyuyv_top_x
  subs r2,r2,#1          @ y++
  bgt cvtyuyv_top_y
  bx lr
```

Comment: (+1) I think it should be "subs r2,r2,#2", OP mentions _interlaced_ and Y is calculated as *(CAM_WIDTH * 2 * y)*.

Comment: subs r2,r2,#1 is correct. It's reading 16-bytes of YUYV and storing 8 bytes of Y. In the vertical axis (r2 counter), there is no interlacing.

Answer (score 1):

(Promoting my comment to answer)

The least amount of instructions to de-interleave data in NEON architecture is achievable with the sequence:

```
vld2.8 { d0, d1 }, [r0]!
vst1.8 { d0 }, [r1]!
```

Here `r0` is the source pointer, which advances by 16 each time and `r1` is the destination pointer, which advances by 8.

Loop unrolling, ability to retrieve up to 4 registers and offset the registers by 2 can give slightly larger maximum throughput. Coupled with alignment by 16 bytes:

```
start:
vld4.8 { d0, d1, d2, d3 }, [r0:256]
subs r3, r3, #1
vld4.8 { d4, d5, d6, d7 }, [r1:256]
add r0, r0, #64
add r1, r0, #64
vst2.8 { d0, d2 }, [r2:256]!
vst2.8 { d4, d6 }, [r2:128]!
bgt start
```

(I can't remember if the format `vstx.y {regs}, [rx, ro]` exists -- here ro is offset register, that post-increments rx)

While memory transfer optimizations can be useful, it's still better to think, if it can be skipped all together, or merged with some calculation. Also this could be the place to consider planar pixel format, which could completely avoid the copying task.